# Autocomplete Search Bar Container Hidden on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

**Found a solution:**

**Added a class with display:none:**

```
   .hidden { display: none; }
```

**And added this function:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.preview').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

---

I have a search bar using JS Autocomplete, with a container (preview) and a left table (leftspan) and the results unordered list.

I have this script to show the list and hide the results dropdown container when you click off of the container:

```
   // Show the ul
$suggestedUL.show();
}
if ($(this).val() == '') {
$suggestedUL.hide();
}
},

focus: function(e) {
if ($(this).val() != '') {
$suggestedUL.show();
}
}
});

$suggestedHL.on('click', 'li', function(e) {
addSuggestion($(this));
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
      if (!$(e.target).closest('.suggest-holder li, .leftspan, .suggest-holder input').length) {
           $suggestedUL.hide();
           $preview.hide();
       };
});
```

However, when the page loads for the first time, the empty preview div is visible (it has a 1px border) 
[image: preview div visible on page load]

Also, if I try to click back to the list after typing in a search in the input field, the script above continues to hide it.

**Is there a better function to write instead of hide, so that the div will be hidden on page load, but still functions after clicking out of the input field and going back to it again?**

FULL HTML, JS AND CSS BELOW:

```js
var data = [{
  image: src = "a.jpg",
  name: 'apples',
  sku: '61583318'
  },
  {
  image: src = "b.jpg",
  name: 'oranges',
  sku: '924335'
  },
  {
  image: src = "c.jpg",
  name: 'strawberries',
  sku: '73940'
  },
  {
      image: src = "d.jpg",
      name: 'string bans',
      sku: '66155'
  },
  {
      image: src = "e.jpg",
      name: 'grapes',
      sku: '112509'
  },
  {
      image: src = "f.jpg",
      name: 'apricots',
      sku: '112984'
 }];

    
    // Suggest Holder
    var $suggestedHL = $('.suggest-holder');
    // Suggestions UL
    var $suggestedUL = $('ul', $suggestedHL);
    // Suggestions LI
    var $suggestedLI = $('li', $suggestedHL);
    // Selected Items UL
    var $selectedUL = $('#selected-suggestions');
    // Preview Div
    var $preview = $('.preview');
    // Keyboard Nav Index
    var index = -1;

    function addSuggestion(el) {
    $selectedUL.append($('<li>' + el.find('.suggest-name').html() + '</li>'));
    }

    $('input', $suggestedHL).on({
    keyup: function(e) {
    var m = false;
    if (e.which == 38) {
    if (--index < 0) {
    index = 0;
    }

    m = true;
    } else if (e.which == 40) {
    if (++index > $suggestedLI.length - 1) {
    index = $suggestedLI.length - 1;
    }

    m = true;
    }

    if (m) {
    // Remove the active class
    $('li.active', $suggestedHL).removeClass('active');
    $suggestedLI.eq(index).addClass('active');
    } else if (e.which == 27) {
    index = -1;
    // Esc key
    $suggestedUL.hide();
    } else if (e.which == 13) {
    // Enter key
    if (index > -1) {
    addSuggestion($('li.active', $suggestedHL));
    index = -1;
    $('li.active', $suggestedHL).removeClass('active');
    }
    } else {
    index = -1;
    // Clear the ul
    $suggestedUL.empty();


    // Cache the search term
    $search = $(this).val();

    // Search regular expression
    $search = new RegExp($search.replace(/[^0-9a-z_]/i), 'i');

    // update the left box below search
    $('.leftspan').html('<span class="searching"><b>' + $('.suggest-prompt').val() + '</b></span><b><i> in Category XXX</i></b>');


    // Loop through the array
    for (var i in data) {
    if (data[i].name.match($search)) {
    $suggestedUL.append($("<li><span class='suggest-name'>" + data[i].name + "</span><span class='suggest-sku'>" + data[i].sku + "</span><img src=" + data[i].image + " class='suggest-image' /></li>"));
    }
    }


    // Show the ul
    $suggestedUL.show();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $suggestedUL.hide();
    }
    },
   
    focus: function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
    $suggestedUL.show();
    }
    }
    });

    $suggestedHL.on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    addSuggestion($(this));
    });

    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
          if (!$(e.target).closest('.suggest-holder li, .leftspan, .suggest-holder input').length) {
               $suggestedUL.hide();
               $preview.hide();
           };
    });
```

```css
body {background-color:#eeeeee;}
  
  .preview {
    border: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
    background-color: GREEN;
    width:63%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
}
 .preview ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top:5px;
    width: 65%;
  }

  .preview:li {
    padding: 5px;
    position: inherit;
  }

  li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  li:hover,
  li.active {
    background: rgba(100, 100, 100, .2);
  }
}

.suggest-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.suggest-sku {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: $font-size-small;
  color: $gray-light;
}

.suggest-image {
  height: 35px;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
}

.leftspan {
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.searching {
  color: $brand-primary;
}

header .search-block {
  input {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    width: 65% !important;
    @media (max-width: $screen-xs) {
      width: 47% !important;
    }
  }
  select {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    width: 20% !important;
    @media (max-width: $screen-xs) {
      width: 30% !important;
    }
  }
  button {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 14% !important;
    @media (min-width: $screen-lg) {
      width: 8% !important;
    }
    @media (max-width:$screen-xs) {
      width: 21% !important;
    }
  }
  .form-group {
    > form {
      > * {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      @media (max-width:$screen-xs) {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        @include pad-sides(0);
      }
    }
  }
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
  <form class="navbar-form suggest-holder">
    <input class="form-control input-lg suggest-prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      <select class="form-control input-lg">
      <option>All</option>
      <option>one</option>
      <option>two</option>
      <option>three</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Go</button>
        <div class="preview">
          <div class="leftspan">
          </div>
        <ul id='selected-suggestions' class="inlineblock selected-suggestions"></ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can not reproduce that issue with shown suggestion box

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work, so I cannot update your code - but absolutely the best way to go about this is to hide with `display: none`, then add a class with jQuery at the appropriate time.